# lossy conversion from float to int.type checking in java

Tags: java

Why does assigning `5.6` to an `int` produce the `Possible lossy conversion from double to int` error?

```
int i = 5.6;
```

[screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cAvn.png)

Answer (score 3):

A square is a rectangle, but a rectangle is not a square, the same goes here, an integer is a float but a float is not an integer, plus here 5.6 is considered as a double. 5.6f is a float. Use:

```
int i= (int)5.6
```

To convert the double to integer.

```
int i= 5.6f //still won't work, (use the "(int)")
```